# Executing arbitrary C# code in Sandbox mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razorengine

I am using RazorEngine. I have some dynamic templates which I will bind with a view-model at run-time. My requirement is to run-code in a sandbox. So, only bindings will be allowed. RazorEngine allows me to run code in arbitrary app-domain using,

```
using (var service = new IsolatedTemplateService(() => appDomain))
{
   return service.Parse(newTemplate, model, null, null);
}
```

If I run the app-domain with the following permission then it works,

```
var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
```

But If I run it using these permissions,

```
var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
permissionSet.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
permissionSet.AddPermission(new ReflectionPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
```

I will get,

```
[SecurityException: Request failed.]
   System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +0
   RazorEngine.Templating.IsolatedTemplateService..ctor(Language language, Encoding encoding, IAppDomainFactory appDomainFactory) +408
   RazorEngine.Templating.IsolatedTemplateService..ctor(Language language, Encoding encoding, Func`1 appDomainFactory) +73
   RazorEngine.Templating.IsolatedTemplateService..ctor(Func`1 appDomainFactory) +41
```

Is there any special permission I need to grant?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the type of code you wish to allow / disallow?  I'm not sure what you mean when you say that only bindings should be allowed.

Comment: @Levi, Thanks. I only required to run RazorEngine(Razor.Parse) code in a sandbox. Because, I am allowing the user to create Razor HTML template dynamically. Currently, it is very dangerous because user can put arbitrary C# code. I am sure this is possible because dotnetfiddle.net is an example.

Comment: Razor is intended to run arbitrary C# code.  Even if you could sandbox the parser (see Andrew's answer below for why this isn't feasible), once the runtime kicks in you have no way of teasing apart the .cshtml file contents from the Razor engine itself.  Sure, you could revoke code execution permissions, but then the Razor engine wouldn't even run.

Comment: @Levi Thanks. Means currently there is no way. What about creating a separate IIS virtual directory(application) with a very low privileges user app-domain account? Thanks again.

Comment: @Levi, can a custom app-domain run under a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the CodeDOM API (which is likely what RazorEngine uses to generate C# code from the syntax tree that the Razor compiler generates) requires full trust. There's not really anything you can do other than strong-name and GAC your assembly so you get full trust. Unfortunately, because it demands the entire "FullTrust" permission set you can't just grant a specific permission.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Can you give any suggestion to implement allow user to create razor template but not allowing them to put dangerous C# code? Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, i'm having the same problem. Did you found any answer about this question? @user960567

Comment: @Charles use Roslyn if you can?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have strong name assemblies, you need to apply the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute.

[How to use the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839300)

Comment: Thanks. I don't have any strong-name assembly. Might be RazorEngine.dll have. BTW, now I am getting, `Attempt by security transparent method 'TemplateGenerator.Generate(System.String, System.Object, Int32)' to access security critical method 'RazorEngine.Templating.IsolatedTemplateService..ctor(System.Func`1<System.AppDomain>)' failed.`